# spring boot project run on debug mode takes more than 2 hours

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am using intellij idea to run the project

java version **17**

spring boot project build is succeeded.
but when I am start to run the project in Debug mode it takes since 2 hours.

I have tried to add **application.properties** file by added the below line

```
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure=DEBUG
```

[image]

Comment: See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544799 . If you have security software installed make sure that all [IDE](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) and project directories are added to the exclusions list.

Comment: @EgorKlepikov I don't believe it has something to do with "slow performance or hangups" in the debug mode. It's just the nature of the app that the OP is running. More on this is in my answer below. But the links can come in handy, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think it shouldn't be like this?

It's a SpringBoot application that is basically a web server with HTTP endpoints. Those endpoints listen for user requests using a number of threads. E.g. StackOverflow runs their own web server (many of them) to serve  many many user requests like yours and mine. For that to work, those web server processes must always be active (up and running). The same is with your application.

You can dive a bit deeper and see what your application threads are actually up to. To do that you should click "Get Thread Dump" button. Looking at your screenshot I believe you should click the double arrow icon in the bottom left corner and then you will see the photo camera logo. This is the one you should click to take the thread dump. Mine looks like this:
[image]

You can see at least 2 threads are responsible for handling HTTP requests. You will have a similar picture.

Also, it has nothing to do with **Debug** mode. You can do the same in the **Run** mode. The `logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure=DEBUG` option is just for logging, as the name implies. This is why  you can see some Spring AutoConfiguration info in the IDE console. For example, if I run my similar SpringBoot app without that option set to DEBUG I will only see the following in the console (spot the default INFO logging level):
[image]